# Borde gap between status bar and AppBar

Tags: android, statusbar, appbar

[image: default AS Navigation Drawer Activity Project]

I have an issue with a simple Android project I'm styling.

The issue is exactly like the one you can sse by creating and building a default project from Android Studio Navigation Drawer Activity: this template has the navigation drawer that covers also the status bar (like GMail, for example): but as you can see there is something like a gap between the appbar and the status bar.

I really don't like it and I would like to remove it somehow, but the only way I found at the moment (without create a detailed theme from scratch, which would be inconvenient for this simple project) is to put to edit **values-v21/styles.xml** from

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

but unfortunately that also prevents the navigation drawer to be shown full height!
I'm a little upset because I think that there is a very simple solution but I'm still not able to found it!

Comment: not really, but this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703159/android-status-bar-transparent-with-navigation-drawer-appbar-elevation solved my issue.

Comment: I see. You mentioned the nav drawer in your question a couple times, so I just went with that